# Template Haskell: generating code for a function signature with the type class constraints

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I need to generate code for the function signature with type class constraints, for example:

```
fun :: (Ord a) => a -> a
```

I'm using the following signature constructor:

```
SigD Name Type
```

So, I need to generate a type. My best guess is to use the following constructor:

```
ForallT [TyVarBndr] Cxt Type
```

It corresponds to the following declaration (as seen at [Temaplate Haskell documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.13.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#t:Type)):

```
forall <vars>. <ctxt> => <type>
```

But `Cxt` is just a synonym for the list of `Type`'s, and I can't find an appropriate constructor of `Type` for generating a type class constraint. What should I do to generate code for a type class constraint?

Comment: I haven't tried but I think as you want `Ord a`, you need something along `AppT (ConstT (mkName "Ord")) (VarT (nkName "a"))` ...

Comment: If I recall correctly, from TH's perspective a constraint is just a `Type`. (Constraints and types have more or less the same syntax, and with `ConstraintKinds` turned on a constraint can appear syntactically pretty much anywhere a `Type` can.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that, as was mentioned in the comments, TH does not draw a distinction between `Type`s and `Constraint`s (which kind of makes sense, especially now that `ConstraintKinds` is around).  I've generally found inspecting the quasiquoted AST for a specific, concrete, example of whatever I'm trying to implement to be useful when working on generating code with TH that the quasiquoters aren't good enough for. For example, in GHCI:

```
λ> :set -XTemplateHaskell
λ> import Language.Haskell.TH
λ> runQ $ [d|f :: Ord a => a -> a; f = id|]
[SigD f_1 (ForallT [] [AppT (ConT GHC.Classes.Ord) (VarT a_0)] (AppT (AppT ArrowT (VarT a_0)) (VarT a_0))),ValD (VarP f_1) (NormalB (VarE GHC.Base.id)) []]
```

This shows that the constraint portion is just the `Name` for `Ord` applied to the name that you use for the type variable. Note that, at least at this level, the `ForallT` parameter list is empty, since the `a` in the type signature wasn't written as an explicit `forall a.`.